# Did my brother committed shedding the blood of Buddha sin?

Tags: statue

Im too anxious,in the past my brother play football he kicked the ball to Guanyin statue i don't know he is intent or not did he committed shedding the blood of Buddha sin? the statue did not break

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no blood in a statue. Therefore, the soccer ball your brother kicked did not shed the blood of a Buddha. Buddha statutes are *representations* of the Buddha rather than the Buddha himself.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the five *anantarika-karma* are described in [AN 5.129](https://suttacentral.net/an5.129/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=true&script=latin):

> Murdering your mother or father or a perfected one; maliciously shedding the blood of a Realized One; and causing a schism in the Saṅgha.

The same phrase is used in [AN 6.87](https://suttacentral.net/an6.87/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=true&script=latin):

> They murder their mother or father or a perfected one. They maliciously shed the blood of a Realized One. They cause a schism in the Saṅgha. They’re witless, dull, and stupid.

The phrase translated there as, "they maliciously shed the blood", includes *duṭṭhena cittena* -- i.e. something like, "evil-minded" (see [duṭṭha](https://suttacentral.net/define/du%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADha?lang=en) and [citta](https://suttacentral.net/define/citta?lang=en)).

Some people interpret or expand on "shedding blood" as including, "harming the dharma" -- for example, by destroying sutras.

Comment: Which people say shedding blood is burning books?

Comment: I think that is what is behind the OP -- i.e. a doctrine about 'harming the Dharma', by for example destroying sutras or even statues -- which, I suppose is related to doctrine about the [dharmakaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmak%C4%81ya). I presume it's a tradition or country other than Theravada -- the OP also mentions Guanyin. Although as an aside re Theravada, the Pali suttas include the last paragraph of [SN 22.87](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.087x.wlsh.html) which seems to equate (seeing) the Buddha's person with the Dhamma.